# Simplifying not equal && condition

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to simplify the following condition?

```
var test = "";
var a = "NA";
var b = "valid";

answer = (v:string)=> {
     test = v!==a && v!==b; //this condition here
}
```

Where both `v` doesn't equal `a` or `b`?

I tried `v!==(a&&b)` but doesn't seem to be the case.

Let me know if the above is already the simplest version of the condition,
Thanks!

Comment: You assign the result to `test` but don't return anything from the function so `answer` doesn't get assigned either

Comment: sorry just assume the test is a "this.test" variable

Comment: `test = ![a,b].includes(v)`

Answer (score 3):

```
(v: string) => { 
  test = [a,b].every(x => x !== v); 
}
```

or

```
(v: string) => { 
  test = ![a,b].includes(v); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematically speaking

According to [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) you can always invert your expression as following:

1. `(not x) and (not y)` is the same as `not (x or y)`
2. `(not x) or (not y)` is the same as `not (x and y)`

You have first case, where `not x = v!==a` and `not y = v!==b`, i.e. `x = v === a` and `y = v === b`. Eventually inversion in your case will look like the following:

```
answer = (v:string)=> {
     test = !(v === a || v === b); //this condition here
}
```

#### Note about Intellij IDEA products (WebStorm, Intellij, PyCharm, ...)

If you will put your cursor on the `condition` in `if` statement and then press `Alt+Enter` you can choose option "Invert 'if' condition" that will apply De Morgan's Law automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can create an object with states:

```
let test = "";
let states = {
    NA: 1,
    valid: 1,
    'Not Valid': 1
}

const answer = (v) => states[v];
```

An example:

```js
let test = "";
let states = {
    NA: 1,
    valid: 1,
    'Not Valid': 1
}

const answer = (v) => states[v];


const na = 'NA';
const valid = 'valid';
const notValid = 'Not Valid';
console.log(na, answer(na))
console.log(valid, answer(valid))
console.log(notValid, answer(notValid))
```

One of the advantages of this approach is it is not necessary to edit `answer()` method, just add states to `states` object.